# Can we use External Accessory framework for wifi?

Tags: iphone, hardware-interface

By searching and reading the documentation I found that I can connect to external device by bluetooth and USB port but I did not found any thing by connecting wifi .
Can I use External Accessory framework for
1:My device is only supporting wifi
2:what if my device is not programmed for IOS?

Please help

Answer (score 0):

I don't get your point. WiFi access to a device rely on standard BSD network layer.

You just have to implement an TCP/IP server (or client, depending on your device specs) in you application.

Comment: I think this becomes important when writing an app that relies on communication to the external accessory when in the background.  Unless you use the external devices framework and set the external accessory key in the info.plist your app will be suspended when in the background.